# How to get values from XML Node that has many values

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I have an xml response which look similar to this..

**XML**

```
<room type="Petite Double " mealtype="Room Only" roomid="62926:0" price="12065.43" allocation_status="A">
```

How do i get all the value separately in XSLT..say for example type,mealtype,price,roomid,allocationstatus..

IF there is one value then i will use

**XSLT**

```
<xsl:value-of select="/room">
```

Now there are many..please help me with sample code..

Thanks in advance..

Comment: In which language you want to parse your XML file ?

Comment: Please identify the language you want to use to parse the xml.

Comment: i develop my appllication in c#..I use xslt to format and display as a table in xml control in .Net..

Comment: I use c#..But i dont want to use it to parse..I want to do only with xslt..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the values use;

```
<xsl:value-of select="/room/@AttributeName">
```

Comment: Great answer! If you want to expand your stylesheet, templates also work on attributes. Use an `@` to mark the names as attributes, like in the answer. However, the compiler by default ignores attributes when trying to match the templates. You make it do so by using `<xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>` - the `select="@*"` matches the attributes explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

```
using (XmlReader myReader = XmlReader.Create(@"c:\data\YourXml_File.xml"))
    {
        while (myReader.Read())
        {
           // Process each node (myReader.Value) here
           // ...
        }
    }
```

Here is the code you can try it. Working perfect for me

Comment: Bro i want to parse it in xslt, not c#